# Algorithm to find all acyclic orientations of a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, counting

I am working on acyclic orientations of undirected graphs and have the following questions:

1. Given connected undirected simple graph $G$, how to find all possible acyclic orientations of $G$ ?
2. What is the number of acyclic orientations? 
   It is known (from [here](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/18.pdf)) to be $(-1)^p\ \chi(G,-\lambda)$ for a graph $G$ with $p$ vertices where $\chi$ is the chromatic polynomial evaluated at $-\lambda$; but I wasn't successful in understanding how to evaluate $\chi$ at a negative value ($-\lambda$).

Comment: Re 2, $\chi(G,\cdot)$ is just a polynomial. It can be evaluated at any complex point. The number of acyclic orientations is $(-1)^p \chi(G,-1)$, where $p$ is the number of vertices. For example, the chromatic polynomial of a triangle is $t(t-1)(t-2)$, and so the number of acyclic orientations is $(-1)^3(-1)(-2)(-3) = 6$ (all $2^3$ orientations other than the $2$ cyclic orientations).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks a lot. so its a matter of evaluating the polynomial at $-\lambda$.

Answer (score 5):

As Yuval noted, you can count the number of acyclic orientations by evaluating the chromatic polynomial of a graph at negative unity. For computing chromatic polynomials, there are efficient algorithms known for [some graph classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Efficient_algorithms).

There is also a recursive algorithm for generating *all* acyclic orientations of a graph given by Squire [1]. The algorithm requires $O(n)$ time per acyclic orientation generated. Roughly 20 years ago this was the fastest algorithm known; it's possible a faster one is known now, or that you can improve Squire's algorithm by known techniques.

---

[1] [Squire, M. B. (1998). Generating the acyclic orientations of a graph. Journal of Algorithms, 26(2), 275-290.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677497908919)